# Why is the interior of this set empty?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question reads: In $\mathbb{R}$ (equipped with its standard topology), determine the interior of the set $E$ := {$\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}$}.

Now, in $\mathbb{R}$, $E \equiv (0,1]$. My book states that by definition, the interior of E, is the union of all open sets which are contained in E.

Clearly, the set $(0,1)$ is open with respect to the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and it is also contained in $E$. So wouldn't int($E$) = ($0,1$)?

The solution my professor posted simply states that int($E$) = $\varnothing$. I don't understand how this can be the case.

Thanks.

Comment: $E$ is not equal to $(0,1]$.  Not every real number in $(0,1]$ can be written in the form $1/n$ for a natural number $n$.

Comment: $E=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,... \}$. That is NOT equal to $(0,1]$.

Comment: Is it then also incorrect to say the the closure of E is equal to $[0,1]$? I know that in general cl($E$) = $E \bigcup$ {all limit points of $E$} = $E \bigcup$ {$0$}

Comment: Yes, that is also incorrect.

Comment: @Javier You are right saying that $cl'E)=E \cup \{0\}$, so... it is $\{1/n\}_n \cup \{0\}$, and that is of course not $[0,1]$ (draw a picture, it is just your original set -- not at all an interval -- plus zero !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say the interior is the union of every open set included in $E$. What are the open sets in $\mathbf{R}$? The ones containing an open interval, generically $(a,b)$.

Now, is there any nonempty $(a,b)$ included in $E$? The answer is no: for every $(a,b)$, either it does not cut $E$, or there is a $1/n$ in $(a,b)$, but then any $1/n + \varepsilon$, for $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough, is in $(a,b)$ but not in $E$, hence $(a,b)$ is not included in $E$. At last, no nonempty $(a,b)$ is contained is $E$, that is no non-trivial open set, that is to say $E$ has empty interior.

*Graphically*, $E$ is purely discrete, it consists in isolated points, you have no open (=balls=intervals) in it: for each point of $E$, its neighbors are not inside.